# tf.TFRecordReader returns multiples copies of the same data with only 1 epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to evaluate a model as fast as possible. I get my examples from an only TFRecords file and it seems to be extremely slow, so I searched for any explanation here and I found a sample code from Yaroslav Bulatov (https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/ericyue-slowreader/benchmark.py).

I have replaced the tf.train.shuffle_batch call by tf.train.batch because I need to read only 1 epoch and I don't mind if the samples are shuffled or not. When enqueue_many=False, the result is right, however, when I tried enqueue_many=True with 2 enqueued items, I got the same sample duplicated.

The key code is here:

```
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    queue_batch = []
    for i in range(enqueue_many_size):
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        queue_batch.append(serialized_example)
    batch_serialized_example = tf.train.batch(
        [queue_batch],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=thread_number,
        capacity=capacity,
        enqueue_many=True)
```

And the complete proof of concept is here:

```
import glob
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf

epoch_number = 1
thread_number = 1
batch_size = 4
capacity = thread_number * batch_size + 10
enqueue_many = True
enqueue_many_size = 2

# Just in case that you want to generate my set of samples
def generateNumbersTFRecords(directory, num_elements):
    record_filename = os.path.join(directory, 'vectors.tfrecords')
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(record_filename)
    for i in range(num_elements):
        vector = np.arange(i*16,(i+1)*16, dtype=np.float32)
        feature = {'vector': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=vector.tolist()))}
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()


filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
      ["vectors.tfrecords"],
      shuffle=False,
      seed = int(time.time()),
      num_epochs=epoch_number)

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    return serialized_example

if enqueue_many:
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    queue_batch = []
    for i in range(enqueue_many_size):
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        queue_batch.append(serialized_example)
    batch_serialized_example = tf.train.batch(
        [queue_batch],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=thread_number,
        capacity=capacity,
        enqueue_many=True)

else:
    serialized_example = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
    batch_serialized_example = tf.train.batch(
        [serialized_example],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        num_threads=thread_number,
        capacity=capacity)

features = tf.parse_example(
    batch_serialized_example,
    features={
        "vector": tf.FixedLenFeature([16], tf.float32),
    })


batch_values = features["vector"]

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        f1 = sess.run([batch_values])
        print(f1)


except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print("Done training after reading all data")
finally:
    coord.request_stop()
    print("coord stopped")

coord.join(threads)
```

I would like to prevent two calls to a reader from returning the same TFRecord when used in enqueue_many context. The expected behaviour would be sequential vectors [[0,1,2,3...15],[16,17...]...], however I get [[0,1,2,3...15],[0,1,2,3...15],[16,17...],[16,17...]...

My output is this:

```
[array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
     11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
   [  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
     11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.],
   [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,
     27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.],
   [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,  25.,  26.,
     27.,  28.,  29.,  30.,  31.]], dtype=float32)]
[array([[ 32.,  33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.,  42.,
     43.,  44.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
   [ 32.,  33.,  34.,  35.,  36.,  37.,  38.,  39.,  40.,  41.,  42.,
     43.,  44.,  45.,  46.,  47.],
   [ 48.,  49.,  50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,  55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,
     59.,  60.,  61.,  62.,  63.],
   [ 48.,  49.,  50.,  51.,  52.,  53.,  54.,  55.,  56.,  57.,  58.,
     59.,  60.,  61.,  62.,  63.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this question as an issue in tensorflow's github and luckily @yaroslavvb answered quickly and gave me the solution. Just in case you are stuck in the same place that I was, you must know that the problem is related to the optimization options. It is an known bug of TF 1.0 and it has been solved in the master branch.

You can find more information here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7916